# Ideas for a tagline for CrossFit StarFit?

Tags: training, gym, crossfit

Just putting together a design for a t-shirt for my recently affiliated CrossFit Gym, and was wondering if anyone could help with a tagline that might be appropriate? The gym is targeted mainly as middle aged women and teens but would like to target guys as well, so don't want anything that will scare guys off.
Currently training people outdoors, but do plan to move into a space eventually, so nothing that limits me to staying outside,

Any thoughts or ideas welcome!
Thanks!

Comment: Please read the [faq] your question is off topic here.

Comment: Well actually it is both off topic and _too localized_, I think in this case the too localized bit counts most. We generally try to produce questions and answers here that are applicable for more than one specific moment in time (you looking for a tagline). It might be possible to rephrase your question to make it fit the scope of our site, but I don't see how this could be done right now.

Comment: Hi CFstarfit, and I would like to grant you a warm welcome to our site.  Thank you for your question, and I hope you get the responses you are looking for.

Comment: Doesn't CF have a forum where you can ask such questions?

Answer (score 2):

Just my 5 cent:

- Starfit makes me fit on time.
- Starfit will shape on time.
- I flip tires on time to get fit.
- Just to look better naked.
- Get result on time.
- Time-Intensity-Result

Here is a site [tagline](http://www.taglineguru.com/ten_tagline_mistakes.html) guru with some advice.